# Why different results when deserializing objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I noticed that I would get different results when deserializing objects different ways. I must have missed something but couldn't figure out what.

Here is the json:

```
  {
    "content_version": "1",
    "date_created": "2020-10-06T13:52:15.288Z",
    "date_updated": "2020-10-06T13:54:24.325Z",
    "content": {
      "EN": {
        "name_full": {
          "text": "Test"
        },
        "name_short": {
          "text": "TEST"
        }
      }
    },
      "tools": {
            "car": true,
            "truck": true,
            "fleet": {
              "use": true,
              "languages": [
                {
                  "fileName": "file1.json",
                  "name": {
                    "text": "English"
                        }
                }
              ]
      }
    }
  }
```

The following are the classes that I generated using a tool:

```
    public class Root
    {
      public string content_version { get; set; }
      public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
      public DateTime date_updated { get; set; }
      public ContentRootObject content { get; set; }
      public Tools tools { get; set; }
  }

  public class ContentRootObject
  {
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "content")]
      public Dictionary<string, ContentItem> DataItems { get; set; }
  }

  public class ContentItem
  {
      public NameFull name_full { get; set; }
      public NameShort name_short { get; set; }

  }  

  public class Tools
  {
      public bool car { get; set; }
      public bool truck { get; set; }
      public Fleet fleet { get; set; }
  }

  public class NameFull
  {
      public string text { get; set; }
  }

  public class NameShort
  {
      public string text { get; set; }
  }

  public class EN
  {
      public NameFull name_full { get; set; }
      public NameShort name_short { get; set; }
  }

 

  public class Name
  {
      public string text { get; set; }
  }

  public class Language
  {
      public string fileName { get; set; }
      public Name name { get; set; }
  }

  public class Fleet
  {
      public bool use { get; set; }
      public List<Language> languages { get; set; }
  }
```

and here is the code that I tried for deserializing :

```
        var objTool = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tools>(json); 
        var objRoot = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
        var objContent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContentRootObject>(json)
```

and here is what I got for each of the objects:

```
        objTool: 'fleet' was returned as null in 'tools'
        objRoot: the DataItems of 'content' was null.
        objContent: got an error saying "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'content.EN', line 1, position 146."
```

Although I can just deserialize the whole thing, I only need objTool and objContent and I was wondering what I did wrong in the above code? Thanks!

Comment: you are getting different results because you are *telling* the deserializer that you want different results. the type parameter tells the function **what class** to deserialize **the whole input** as. it does _not_ tell it what _part_ of the data you want. to put it simple: yes, you _have_ to deserialize the whole thing - and to the class that _actually_ represents the structure. (there are ways to avoid this, but none of them are recommendable, performant, stable, or sane. don't think about them.)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann If I deserialize the whole thing, I still got the DataItems of 'content' as null -- I was trying to deserialize the content property to dictionary<sting, object>.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the class that you have as a wrapper for the dictionary is not represented in the JSON.  It'll deserialize the dictionary if you change the root object to this:

```
public class Root
{
    public string content_version { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_updated { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ContentItem> content { get; set; }
    public Tools tools { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem!